# How come that D3.js can select an element that jQuery can't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, d3.js

```
d3.select('#le'+j.toString()).style("background-color", j==i?"#ffffaf":"#dfdfdf");
    //$('#le'+j.toString()).style("background-color", j==i?"#ffffaf":"#dfdfdf");
```

Works.

```
//d3.select('#le'+j.toString()).style("background-color", j==i?"#ffffaf":"#dfdfdf");
    $('#le'+j.toString()).style("background-color", j==i?"#ffffaf":"#dfdfdf");
```

Does not work. I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `.style()` method. Use the `.css()` method instead..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to be

```
$('#le'+j.toString()).css("background-color", j==i?"#ffffaf":"#dfdfdf");
```

instead of

```
$('#le'+j.toString()).style("background-color", j==i?"#ffffaf":"#dfdfdf");
```